# ideviceinfo.exe returns Lockdownd Error Code -2

Tags: c#, ios, .net, libimobiledevice

i have a project that is actually working with the libimobiledevice library that is executed by the ideviceinfo.exe binaries for windows. I have been using it for quite some time now and it works from iPhone 6 to iPhone X.

However, with the emergence of iPhone XS, XR, and XS Max - it stopped working and returned me with an error: `ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -2`. I tried updating my iTunes and downloading latest version of the executable package from multiple GitHub Sources such as [this](https://github.com/iFred09/libimobiledevice-windows), [this](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/imobiledevice/tools/ideviceinfo/), and [this](https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/imobiledevice-net).

I also searched google for errors concerning Lockdownd -2 but all i see is Lockdownd -8 and others.

Hope to get a hint here, thanks.

Below are screenshots for reference and i'm working on iPhone XS / XR / XS Max with iOS 12+ Loaded.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the of the [imobiledevice-net](https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/imobiledevice-net/) project you mentioned. We've recently switched build systems and it looks like I forgot to update the status badge.

The binaries [from the latest build](https://dev.azure.com/libimobiledevice-win32/imobiledevice-net/_build/latest?definitionId=1&branchName=master) should work. On that page, click **Artifacts**, then select **Binaries** and download the `libimobiledevice.1.2.1-r371-win-x64.zip` file.

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: hi mate. sorry but where exactly can i find that "Artifacts" element to click? i can only view this page upon redirect: [link](https://i.imgur.com/zx2vKmr.png)

Comment: The artifacts element is the blue box in the upper-right corner of the page :)

Comment: oh god, i'm really sorry i didn't notice that one. i was so focused on the left pane. hehe. anyway, i'll try it now. thank you so much.

Comment: UPDATE: i just confirmed that the ideviceinfo is back working again. all thanks to you @frederik-carlier for being able to find this question and answering asap.

i just have one question tho: how about the idevicediagnostics when checking the ioreg registry with AppleARMPMUCharger parameter when dumping the battery diagnostics information. it seems to return me empty xml document?